# How to get Realtek ALC887 5.1 sound detected in debian?

Tags: debian, audio, realtek

I have motherboard based on z170 chipset which have next string in specs:

Realtek® ALC887 codec

it has 5.1(3 connectors) and stereo(1 connector) connectors not counting Line In and microphone connectors on back side.

I have 5.1 sound system connected to right connectors. But detected audio cards are next:

```
 lspci -v |grep udio

 00:1f.3 Audio device: Intel Corporation Device a170 (rev 31)
 06:00.1 Audio device: NVIDIA Corporation GK104 HDMI Audio Controller (rev a1)
```

One of which is named as:

```
  Built-in Audio digital Stereo IEC958
```

and other

```
  GK104 HDMI ...bla bla bla 5.1 .
```

in KMix Select Master Channel dialog window.

How to get detected 5.1 audio for ALC887 if i am right about previous questions?

Also

```
lsmod|grep snd
```

Gives next output:

```
snd_hda_codec_hdmi     45118  1 
snd_hda_codec_realtek    67127  1 
snd_hda_codec_generic    63181  1 snd_hda_codec_realtek
snd_hda_intel          26327  5 
snd_hda_controller     26646  1 snd_hda_intel
snd_hda_codec         104463  5            snd_hda_codec_realtek,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_controller
snd_hwdep              13148  1 snd_hda_codec
snd_pcm                88662  4     snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_controller
snd_timer              26614  1 snd_pcm
snd                    65244  18     snd_hda_codec_realtek,snd_hwdep,snd_timer,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_pcm,snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_intel
soundcore              13026  2 snd,snd_hda_codec
```

Comment: Reinstallation of pulseaudio solved the problem, possibly temporarily solved.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Installing pulseaudio from Stretch(testing) release & reinstalling pulseaudio solved the problem. 5.1 sound system now detected in KMix select master channel dialog.

```
sudo apt-get purge pulseaudio
sudo apt-get clean && sudo apt-get autoremove
```

Reboot. Open a terminal again and type (ignore any errors with the rm command):

```
rm -r ~/.pulse ~/.asound* ~/.pulse-cookie ~/.config/pulse
sudo apt-get install pulseaudio
```

Comment: unfortunately this didn't do anything for me

Answer (score 0):

I had to uninstall pulseaudio and use alsa instead.
Once I removed pulseaudio and restarted, I see HDA Intel PCH settings in kmix.

Weird thing was, even with pulseaudio installed, I could still run `alsamixer` and see those settings, but pulse would only find dummy audio.

I'm fine without pulse for now. I'll update this answer if an application I need fails to function.

Edit: Debian 11 amd64 with non-free enabled, recently installed. Attempted accepted answer but it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

A bit of background: The codec (ALC887) is an extra chip that is connected to the Intel HDA (High Definition Audio) generic sound "card" (it's not a card, but part of the chipset).

That's why you don't see any ALC887 when you do `lspci`.

The module `snd_hda_codec_realtek` is responsible for driving the codec. So your codec is detected just fine. The kernel drivers work with the ALSA layer, which is why ALSA also works fine.

However, there is a bug in more recent Pulseaudio that prevents it from picking up that ALSA device. You can see that if you look at the messages Pulseaudio generates when starting.

This is why fiddling with different Pulseaudio versions fixed it temporarily, and this is also why you still see everything in alsamixer even when running Pulseaudio.

So your question should really be titled "Pulseaudio doesn't pick up my soundcard".

I am currently suffering from the same bug, but I haven't found a workaround yet. I guess options are compiling older Pulseaudio versions by hand, or trying to fiddle with the Pulseaudio configuration files.